# macOS Catalina official release date

Tags: macos

There are many rumoured release dates for macOS Catalina, most sources say October.

Is there an official release date?

Comment: Ask Apple... they will know

Comment: @SolarMike how am i meant to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has not publicly announced the release date yet.

[Their official Catalina page](https://www.apple.com/macos/catalina/) states it will be available in October 2019.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

macOS Catalina was [eventually released](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2019/10/macos-catalina-is-available-today/) on the 7th October, 2019.